# Kotlin: Kotlin-script (.kts) cannot use regular code?

Tags: kotlin, scripting

In my library's codebase, I have this package function: `fun sayHello() = println("Hello there!")`
The function is defined in the package `org.jire.pomade`

I would like to use this function in a *.kts* file like so: `sayHello()`

Unfortunately I can't seem to get code apart from Kotlin's own stdlib to work in Kotlin-script files.

The entirety of my script:

```
import org.jire.pomade.sayHello

sayHello()
```

The result of running the script:

```
pomade.kts:1:12: error: unresolved reference: jire
import org.jire.pomade.sayHello
           ^
pomade.kts:3:1: error: unresolved reference: sayHello
sayHello()
^
```

Anybody know why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you running the script?

Comment: I tried to run a script with IJ run configuration - no luck, same error as here

Comment: Looks like a bug to me

Comment: @yole I'm running it from IntelliJ like this: http://i.imgur.com/JgHvMfA.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in the Kotlin plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11618

Comment: Even if the bug is marked as "Fixed", this still does seem to work.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest to use [holgerbrandl/kscript](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript) to manage dependencies of your script.

Answer (score 4):

There is experimental support for maven imports in Kotlin scripts since 1.3.

Take a look at https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/09/kotlin-1-3-rc-is-here-migrate-your-coroutines/#scripting:

```
@file:Repository("https://jcenter.bintray.com")
@file:DependsOn("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-jvm:0.6.11")

import kotlinx.html.*
import kotlinx.html.stream.*

print(createHTML().html {
    body {
        h1 { +"Hello, World!" }
    }
})
```

And here is the KEEP: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/scripting-support.md.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative is using the Kotlin REPL instead.