# Intellij IDEA does not add maven dependencies to kotlin script classpath

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am trying to run a Kotlin script from Intellij Idea but the dependencies defined in the pom.xml are not added to the classpath. On the **Run configuration** page there is no **Use classpath of module** option like it is for Kotlin or Java. I would expect the IDE to pass a `-classpath` parameter to the `org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler` because if I do it manually all is working fine.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

*noclasspath.kts*

```
import org.slf4j.MDC

val osf = MDC.getMDCAdapter()
val a = "Monkey"
println("$a is big")
```

*pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.whatever</groupId>
    <artifactId>whyunowork</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>

    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.0.4</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs><sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir><sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs><sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir><sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>testCompile</goal> </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is what I get when I run it from IDEA:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_92/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/Development/.IdeaIC2016.2/config/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-compiler.jar:/home/Development/.IdeaIC2016.2/config/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/home/Development/.IdeaIC2016.2/config/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler -script /home/Development/project/src/main/kotlin/noclasspath.kts
noclasspath.kts:1:12: error: unresolved reference: slf4j
import org.slf4j.MDC
           ^
onyad.kts:3:11: error: unresolved reference: MDC
val osf = MDC.getMDCAdapter()
          ^

Process finished with exit code 1
```

IDEA about page:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5
Build #IC-162.2228.15, built on October 14, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-287-b2 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Kotlin plugin version

```
1.0.4-release-IJ2016.1-112
```

Comment: Hi Frigo, I tried to do the same here, but then with Gradle, but you're not missing anything, it's just unsupported right now. The state of .kts files is a bit unclear anyway at the moment, I wouldn't expect too much of it.

Comment: I just find it weird that the dependencies are "added to the module" (I am not sure what the right term is), that is they show up in the Module settings and the editor does code completion and all, but running the script is not possible. Like running a marathon and stopping few meters in front of the finish line. Something you just don't do.Anyways, thanks for your input, fun main it is!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210011/kotlin-kotlin-script-kts-cannot-use-regular-code as well.